# Login via Auth0 on React Project

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

I have a simple basic react app login via Auth0.

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

import NotFoundPage from "./components/NotFoundPage";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";

import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: (
            <>
                <App />
            </>
        ),
    },
    {
        path: "/dashboard",
        element: (
            <>
                <Dashboard />
            </>
        ),
    },
    {
        path: "*",
        element: (
            <>
                <NotFoundPage />
            </>
        ),
    },
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Auth0Provider domain={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN} clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID} redirectUri={`${window.location.origin}/dashboard`}>
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </Auth0Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**Flows:**
After clicking login, I saw the login form, put in the right credentials, clicked allow, and was redirected to the `/dashboard` page as expected.

Since that happened, I don't understand why `isAuthenticated` variable kept returning `false` value which leads to displayong the wrong view.❌

[image]

How can I debug this further?